# Converting big number string to number

Tags: javascript, typescript, numbers

What way i can convert string with 16 digits and 2 fraction value to number ?

Currently when I try to convert `Number('1234567890123456.12')` will became to `1234567890123456`. fraction values will be gone.

I just want to confirm without using any third party lib can i convert this string to number ?

Comment: Number function gives you result with out fraction part, do you want to keep fraction part

Comment: Your number is too big, around `9007199254740991` is the highest safe integer in JS, and the way numbers are stored, even though `1234567890123456.12` seems "smaller", it is in fact "longer"

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately not. Javascript represents it's numbers using double precision floating point numbers. At 16 digits, it will only be able to store the integer component and not the part after the decimal point. You will need a bignum library to use this value.

EDIT: for reference the biggest integer you can use in JavaScript is 9,007,199,254,740,991

EDIT2: Thanks to Jeremy you can use a library like [bignumberJS](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/).

Comment: ...a library like [bignumberJS](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)

Answer (score 1):

Your number has too many algorisms, I've created an example that simulates in the first position of the array the maximum length possible in javascript.

```
var nums = [
    "12345678910111.12", 
    "1.5323",  
    "-42.7789"
];

nums.forEach(function(n) {
    console.log(parseFloat(n).toFixed(2));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7zzz1qzt/

Answer (score 0):

I have faced issue to convert 18 digit string number to number. It is convert all digit to 0 after 16 digit. I have apply below code. it is working fine for me.

`[{"id":${id},"name":"${name}"}]`