# Converting String to Number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, numbers

I'm stuck in small problem where I'm trying to convert String to number but that String number is huge due to which it is not properly converting to number type.

```js
str = "6145390195186705543"
num = Number(str)
```

```js
digits = [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]
let str = String(Number(digits.join(''))+1).split('')
```

after performing above operation the value of num is 6145390195186705000 which is not what I was expecting. It should be 6145390195186705543.

It would be very helpful if someone can explain this and tell if there is any alternative way.

- I have tried parseInt() and  '+' as well but nothing is working.

Comment: JavaScript numbers have a limited ability to represent large values with complete accuracy, and your value exceeds that limit.

Comment: You can look into using [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)s, `BigInt("6145390195186705543")`

Comment: Also it would be helpful to know *why* you want that value as a number.

Comment: please confirm this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53971935/convert-a-string-to-a-big-integer-in-javascript

Comment: BigInt is giving 6145390195186705408n, but I want 6145390195186705543.

Comment: @PoojaKushwah then you're doing it incorrectly: `BigInt("6145390195186705543")` returns the correct value.

Comment: It is still not usefull.

Comment: If you are using it purely for calculations, you can use the big int method. Otherwise, call let x = BigInt("6145390195186705543").toLocaleString(). Here x will be your number in string format.

Comment: actually I need to convert that string in number array

Comment: digit = [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3]
let str = String(Number(digits.join(''))+1).split('')  ;
this is what my calculation is .

Comment: So you just want to add one to this, and then split again?

Comment: yes exactly ....

Comment: @PoojaKushwah see my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67639031/1762224) below. Next time you ask a question, please include all relevant code ahead of time. Thanks. The code you just posted in the comment above drastically differs from what you originally asked.

Comment: Then just add 1 to the number you are getting after using BigInt("6145390195186705543"). Use .toString() to convert that number to string if you do not want the commas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment an array of integer values, you can join the digits and pass it to the `BigInt` constructor. After it is a `BigInt`, you can add `1n`. Once you have added the value, you can stringify the value and split it. Lastly, you can map each digit back into an integer.

```js
const digits = [6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 9, 0, 1, 9, 5, 1, 8, 6, 7, 0, 5, 5, 4, 3];
const str = (BigInt(digits.join('')) + 1n).toString().split('').map(digit => +digit);
console.log(JSON.stringify(str)); // [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,4]
```

Here is the code above, modified into a function:

```js
const numArrayAdd = (bigIntSource, bigIntAmount) =>
  (BigInt(bigIntSource.join('')) + bigIntAmount)
    .toString().split('').map(digit => +digit);

const digits = [6, 1, 4, 5, 3, 9, 0, 1, 9, 5, 1, 8, 6, 7, 0, 5, 5, 4, 3];
const str = numArrayAdd(digits, 1n);

console.log(JSON.stringify(str)); // [6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,4]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add just a + right before that variable
here is a good example about that
https://youtu.be/Vdk18Du3AVI?t=61

Comment: you should provide details with some example.